# TYPO3 Render FLUID Template in Backend

Tags: typo3, partial, fluid, extbase

I have an extbase extension with this TCA:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['previewRenderer']['items_item']
= \Vendor\Name\Backend\Preview\PreviewRenderer::class;
```

and this tsconfig:

```
mod.web_layout.tt_content.preview.list.items_item = EXT:EXT/Resources/Private/Templates/Preview/Items.html
```

Everything works well if i write the complete Code in this template file. But if i change it and use Partials like  this:

```
<f:render arguments="{_all}" partial="Preview/List"/>
```

I only get the following error:

```
Error while rendering FluidTemplate preview using /typo3conf/ext/EXT/Resources/Private/Templates/Preview/Items.html The Fluid template files "" could not be loaded.
```

How can i set the Partial and Layout path?
Ive tried ist with module via typoscript but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your PreviewRender is doing.

The `StandardContentPreviewRenderer`  supports only a template-file, no layouts, no partials. It's using a `FluidStandaloneView` and only setting `setTemplatePathAndFilename()` without setting paths for other parts of the template ([`renderContentElementPreviewFromFluidTemplate()`](https://api.typo3.org/master/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_backend_1_1_preview_1_1_standard_content_preview_renderer.html#a7671e67f3d907f5f4c0853e7e70fbfe2)):

```
 protected function ‪renderContentElementPreviewFromFluidTemplate(array $row): ?string
 {
     $tsConfig = BackendUtility::getPagesTSconfig($row['pid'])['mod.']['web_layout.']['tt_content.']['preview.'] ?? [];
     $fluidTemplateFile = '';

     if ($row['CType'] === 'list' && !empty($row['list_type'])
         && !empty($tsConfig['list.'][$row['list_type']])
     ) {
         $fluidTemplateFile = $tsConfig['list.'][$row['list_type']];
     } elseif (!empty($tsConfig[$row['CType']])) {
         $fluidTemplateFile = $tsConfig[$row['CType']];
     }

     if ($fluidTemplateFile) {
         $fluidTemplateFile = GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($fluidTemplateFile);
         if ($fluidTemplateFile) {
             try {
                 $view = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
                 $view->setTemplatePathAndFilename($fluidTemplateFile);
                 $view->assignMultiple($row);
                 if (!empty($row['pi_flexform'])) {
                     $flexFormService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FlexFormService::class);
                     $view->assign('pi_flexform_transformed', $flexFormService->convertFlexFormContentToArray($row['pi_flexform']));
                 }
                 return $view->render();
             } catch (\‪Exception $e) {
                 $this->logger->warning('The backend preview for content element {uid} can not be rendered using the Fluid template file "{file}"', [
                     'uid' => $row['uid'],
                     'file' => $fluidTemplateFile,
                     'exception' => $e,
                 ]);

                 if (‪$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['debug'] && $this->‪getBackendUser()->isAdmin()) {
                     $view = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
                     $view->assign('error', [
                         'message' => str_replace(‪Environment::getProjectPath(), '', $e->getMessage()),
                         'title' => 'Error while rendering FluidTemplate preview using ' . str_replace(‪Environment::getProjectPath(), '', $fluidTemplateFile),
                     ]);
                     $view->setTemplateSource('<f:be.infobox title="{error.title}" state="2">{error.message}</f:be.infobox>');
                     return $view->render();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

If you want more advanced features in your preview, you have to extend/override this method.

---

Update:

`StandaloneView` extends `TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\AbstractTemplateView`, so you have also those setters:

- setTemplate($templateName)
- setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePathAndFilename)
- setTemplateRootPaths(array $templateRootPaths)
- setPartialRootPaths(array $partialRootPaths)
- setLayoutRootPaths(array $layoutRootPaths)

So setting paths for partials in your `‪renderContentElementPreviewFromFluidTemplate()` should solve it:

```
 $view->setPartialRootPaths([
   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:extensionfolder/Resources/Private/Partials'),
 ]);
```

Comment: Yes im using the StandardContentPreviewRenderer. How can i extend this to set the paths for my files?

Comment: Just add `$view->setPartialRootPaths(['EXT:.../Resources/Private/Partials/']);`. Julian also pointed it out in his updated answer.